# Dynamic mailing in SSIS

Tags: ssis

Is there any way in SSIS to send mail dynamically with dynamic subject, dynamic recipients, dynamic body itself? It is possible with database tables but I dont want to use database tables and stored procedures in my package.

Comment: How do you plan on loading SSIS with the data if you don't want to connect to a data source? You'd be better off using a dedicated bulk mail tool like blat.

Answer (score 2):

SSIS is an in-memory ETL (Extract, Transform and Load) tool that is powered by the .NET framework (and some COM hackery). It does have a [Send Mail Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142165.aspx) which is capable of sending emails.

To make them as dynamic as you describe, you'll want to use a combination of Expressions, as Aryadev linked, coupled with [Variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141085.aspx).

Most every thing in SSIS exposes a set of [Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms139733.aspx) that support configuration so what I generally suggest is that people create variables and perform all their expressions on the variables and then assign a variable to a property's expression. While it seems like more work, when you have to troubleshoot a package you'll be grateful. You can set a breakpoint in a package and inspect the current value of a Variable but you can't examine the run-time value of a property.

Finally, unless you're doing ETL stuff in addition to email, I'd skip the overhead of SSIS in favor of just using `sp_send_dbmail` in a TSQL space or call into the .NET smtp library.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Look into [SSIS Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141232%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx).